# How to disable TextField with Toogle in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

How should TextField be properly disabled when using Toogle in swiftUI? The following simple example causes warnings in the console if we disable a TextField that has some value entered in it, deleting it doesn't fix the situation either.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var isToogleOn = false
@State var textFieldValue = ""

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        TextField("Placeholder", text: $textFieldValue)
            .disabled(!isToogleOn)
        Toggle("Activate textField", isOn: $isToogleOn)
        }
    }
}
```

Warnings when textfield is switched off:

> === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 160396 === 2022-01-08 15:27:46.182588+0100 CrochetIo[15460:1558507] [SwiftUI] Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason given by @Asperi is correct, but I would suggest other solution. When switching `Toogle` off, let's drop the focus on the `TextField` and only then disable it.

```
    @State var isToogleOn = false
    @State var textFieldIsDisabled = false
    @State var textFieldValue = ""
    
    @FocusState private var focusField: Field?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Placeholde", text: $textFieldValue)
                .focused($focusField, equals: .textField1)
                .disabled(textFieldIsDisabled)
            Toggle("Activate textField", isOn: $isToogleOn)
                .onChange(of: isToogleOn) { newValue in
                    focusField = nil
                    textFieldIsDisabled = !newValue
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is Apple's logs, so we should not care about them, but if they disturb you, then it is possible to solve that, because they are posted due to `TextField` is still in focus during disable.

The possible approach is to use proxy binding on toggle with injected pre-set side-effect.

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

```
struct ContentViewTestToggleText: View {
    @State var isToogleOn = false
    @State var textFieldValue = ""

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Placeholder", text: $textFieldValue)
                .disabled(!isToogleOn)

            let onToggle = Binding(
                get: { self.isToogleOn },
                set: {
                    if !$0 {
                        UIApplication.shared.endEditing()     // << here !!
                    }
                    
                    self.isToogleOn = $0
                }
            )
            Toggle("Activate textField", isOn: onToggle)
        }
    }
}

extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing() {
        sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```